# Multiple regexp replacements in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to perform a number of replacements on a string: remove non-alphanumeric characters, remove duplicate spaces, and capitalize first characters of individual words. Is it a good practice to create a single regexp expression for all 3 tasks, or will performance take a hit if I split this up in 3 separate preg_replace commands?

Comment: Note : You can capitalize each word with `ucwords` (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ucwords.php), you don't need regex.

Comment: well, the answer is it depends: It depends on the efficiency of your expressions. There are ways that many people try to write regexes that cascade inefficiency. Making an already inefficient regex twice as long by adding a second but equally inefficient clause will exponentially increase the inefficiency (usually including so called 'catastrophic backtracking'). Generally, though, the performance hit of doing separate things with separate expressions is not very significant and it is well worth the maintainability improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two regexes for the first two and then use [ucwords](http://php.net/ucwords). The first two operations aren't suited to be combined and they are fundamentally different (one replaces with nothing, one replaces with a single character of the match). Then, use `ucwords` to avoid using another regex.

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^a-z\s]/i', '', $subject);
$result = preg_replace('/(\s)\s+/i', '$1', $result);
$result = ucwords( $result);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r06lEJ)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't test it, just made up from my mind and i wrote it. =D

Comment: @Ismael - [No](http://codepad.org/FlWQZ8P7), that causes invalid output. You'd need a capturing group around the first `\s`. I'll use that modified version instead of mine as my capturing group will only capture the last iteration of the group. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, making your code more maintainable but slightly less efficient is preferable. Here you have the choice between one monstrous regex that will be painful to debug, or 3 very simple regexes, and I would choose the latter every time. You probably won't even notice a performance difference unless you're parsing millions of strings.

If you would like some good reading, this drive to make things as efficient as possible before they are working properly is known as [Premature Optimization](http://www.keyvan.ms/premature-optimization).

Answer (score 0):

generally less operations is better, but i think you'd need to be dealing with millions of strings before it made any noticeable difference